# Looking for this Fryer family in further records

Tags: england, 19th-century, census-records

I am currently researching the Fryer family and am trying to see if I can another Fryer family in Chester to mine.

The family in question is found on the 1841 census in Chester, Cheshire at George Street:

John, 55
Mary, 55
Henry, 1
Mary, 20
Jane, 15
John, 25

I can't find any of them on the 1851 census in Chester and can't find a birth for a Henry or Mary Fryer that would fit. I think they may be the niece and nephew of John and Mary, especially given their age for having a 1 year old, but I am struggling to validate this.

My Fryer family are William and Catherine Fryer. I think William and John may be brothers as he also had children called Henry, Jane, John and Mary that I have been able to find baptisms for, though the ages are somewhat different.

Can anyone help me find records for this household outside of the 1841 census?

Comment: I suspect 20yo Mary had a child named Henry out of wedlock that was listed and probably raised as a child of Mary's parents.

Comment: Perhaps. There's a marriage of a Henry Fryer and Amelia Allen in Chester in 1868 that lists John as the father. Can't find any baptism to confirm or deny that. Could it be possible that they decided not to get Henry baptised to avoid embarrassment of illegitimacy?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider whether this birth:

```
FRYER, HENRY     
-  
GRO Reference: 1841  M Quarter in OF THE RUNCORN UNION  Volume 19  Page 217
```

might be that of the Henry aged 1 recorded in the 1841 Census, and that Henry may have been the son of Mary aged 20 in the 1841 Census, and born out of wedlock, rather than a brother to her.

It is notable that no maiden name for the mother is recorded in the birth registration, and the age of Mary (about 19) at the time of Henry's birth seems more likely for her to be his mother than Mary's mother Mary who would have been about 54.

I thought Henry's death may be this one:

```
FRYER, HENRY     
0   
GRO Reference: 1851  J Quarter in GREAT BOUGHTON  Volume 19  Page 34
```

While the GRO records Henry's age at death as being "0" it may be notable that The FindMyPast transcription records it as "-" so perhaps his age is missing/illegible on the original document.

However, as [commented by @ColeValleyGirl](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/17441/looking-for-this-fryer-family-in-further-records/17442#comment25851_17442):

> CheshireBMD.org.uk (created from transcriptions of the local indices not the GRO ones)
>   has Henry Fryer aged 0 in 1851 dying in Cheshire West district,
>   Chester Castle sub-district.

it appears that this Henry Fryer may have been less than a year old when he deceased, and so seems unlikely to be the same Henry Fryer.